# Filter dynamodb query result with multiple keys

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, boto3

I'm relatively new to dynamodb so bear with me.
I have a very large dataset that I'm designing an api for. I'm trying to support a route with a `q` query parameter that allows users to narrow down a search like so
`/api/v1/base?q=this<10,that>30,else>20`

My approach is to parse the query string and return appropriate `boto3.dynamodb.conditions.Attr`. So based on the above I have
`Attr('this').lt(10) & Attr('that').lt(30) & Attr('else').lt(20)`

However if I try doing this `botocore` raises an error `Invalid FilterExpression: The expression has redundant parentheses`

This only happens when I combine more than two `attr`'s

I'm not entirely sure what I'm doing wrong so any help would be appreciated

**EDIT**

Here's some of the code

```
def filter_serial_no(serial_no, filter_string):
    try:
        response = table.query(
            KeyConditionExpression=Key('sn').eq(serial_no),
            FilterExpression=Attr('ENGINE_LOAD').gt(32) & Attr('MAF').gt(400) & Attr('SPEED').lt(10)
        )
    except ClientError as e:
        print(e.response['Error']['Message'])
    else:
        return response['Items']
```

RESULTS

`Invalid FilterExpression: The expression has redundant parentheses`

Comment: Can you post the complete query code?

Comment: Ignore the `filter_string` param. I stripped down the code to its basic functionality and hard coded the `filter expression`.

Comment: I'm looking at your code that looks exactly like my own code and I can't see any difference except that mine works, sorry.